# Issue with getting value of object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am attempting to get the value of an object, by using a a random selection on its keys.

This is hooked up with a click event on an element, in this case this particular div, `<div id="magnifying-glass">`. When this is invoked I change the HTML of a container element (`<p id="outputArea"></p>`) to make the changes visible to the user.

When I click that element, I get this message back:

`"Drew a [object Object]continent."`

```js
    $(function() {
   var continents = [{
     id: "europe",
     continent: "Europe",
     message: "Europe It Is!"
   }, {
     id: "asia",
     continent: "Asia",
     message: "Let's Checkout Asia!"
   }, {
     id: "northamerica",
     continent: "North America",
     message: "North America Eh?"
   }, {
     id: "southamerica",
     continent: "South America",
     message: "South America Here We Come!"
   }, {
     id: "australia",
     continent: "Australia",
     message: "We Are Going Australia Mate!"
   }, {
     id: "africa",
     continent: "Africa",
     message: "Time To Go On African Safari!"
   }, {
     id: "antarctica",
     continent: "Antarctica",
     message: "Brrr.. Its Going To Be Cold In Antarctica"
   }];

   $(".notable").css("position", "relative");
   $(".note").hide(); 
   $(".note").each(function() {
     var pos = -$(this).fadeOut() + 'px';
     $(this).css({
       position: 'absolute',
       right: 90,
       bottom: pos
     });
   });

   $(".notable").hover(function() {
     $(this).children(".note").show();
   }, function() {
     $(".note").hide();
   });

   $("#magnifying-glass").click(drawcontinent.bind(this, continents));
 });

 function drawcontinent(randompick) {
   var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
   let continentObject = randompick[chosen];
   $("#outputArea").html("The Continent is " + continentObject.continent +     ".<br />" + continentObject.message + "<br/>Redirecting to continent page...");
   setTimeout(function() {
     var link = $("a[data-continent=" + continentObject.id + "]");
     link.click();
     //alert("Clicked link " + link.text()); // Comment this line and uncomment line above to go to specific page.
   }, 200 );
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="marblejar.js">
  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />

  <title>Learn About THe World</title>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="continentpick">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><strong>Choose Continent Here</strong></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a data-continent="northamerica" href="northamerica.html">North America</a>
      <a data-continent="southamerica" href="southamerica.html">South America</a>
      <a data-continent="europe" href="europe.html">Europe</a>
      <a data-continent="asia" href="asia.html">Asia</a>
      <a data-continent="africa" href="africa.html">Africa</a>
      <a data-continent="australia" href="australia.html">Australia</a>
      <a data-continent="antarctica" ref="antarctica.html">Antarctica</a>


    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="cornerobj">
    <h4><span class="notable">Feeling Lucky? <span class="note">Click magnifying glass to randomly choose continent</span></span> </h4>
    <div id="magnifying-glass">  
    </div>
    <br>
    <strong><p id="outputArea"></p></strong>
</div>

<div class="footerholder">   
    <div class="footer">
    <ul class="bottomlinks">
        <li><b href="#home">Home</b></li>
        <li><b href="#news">News</b></li>
        <li><b href="#contact">Contact</b></li>
        <li><b href="#about">About</b></li>
    </ul>
    </div> 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the `drawcontinent` method.

First of all, the random number you choose is always going to be zero (you call `Math.floor()` on a decimal number between 0 and 1, something like this `0.5412`).

This happens because `Math.random()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between 0 and 1 (not including 1 though) (a decimal number). In order to fetch a number between a range you need to multiply the result from `.random()` with that exclusive number.

You have seven continents, so you need to multiply by 7 (you will get numbers from 0 to 6, which is your object's keys if you enumerate them).

Lastly, I don't understand why you have an object with continent names and a number value which is always 1. And in the `drawcontinent` you subtract that value. Please consider to refactor, maybe change your object to something like this, since you pick based on a random number between 0 and 6:

```
 randompick = {
   "0": "europe",
   "1": "asia",
   "2": "northamerica",
   "3": "southamerica",
   "4": "australia",
   "5": "africa",
   "6": "antarctica",
 }
```

And also, please remove it from global scope, make it private, hide it from global scope.

Anyways, based on current code, in order to pick the continent name based on the key index, you need to use the `Object.keys()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). This method will enumerate all the keys in an object and return an array for you with them included in a string format.

You can pick the key using the following code:

```
Object.keys(randompick)[chosen]
```

You get all the keys in an array by passing the object to the `.keys()` method and you get the key by its index, using the `chosen` random number variable.

`drawcontinent` should be like this:

```
 drawcontinent = function() {
   var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
   console.log(chosen)
   if (chosen < this.europe) {
     this.europe--;
     return "Europe It Is!";
   }
   if (chosen < this.asia) {
     this.asia--;
     return "Let's Checkout Asia!";
   }
   if (chosen < this.northamerica) {
     this.northamerica--;
     return "North America Eh?";
   }
   if (chosen < this.southamerica) {
     this.southamerica--;
     return "South America Here We Come!";
   }
   if (chosen < this.australia) {
     this.australia--;
     return "You've got Australia Mate!";
   }
   if (chosen < this.africa) {
     this.africa--;
     return "Time To Go On African Safari!";
   }
   if (chosen < this.antarctica) {
     this.antarctica--;
     return "Brrr.. Its Going To Be Cold In Antarctica";
   }

   $(function() {
     $("#outputArea").html("Drew a " + Object.keys(randompick)[chosen] + " continent.")
   });

 }
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htx12esf/5/) please.

**Update**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/htx12esf/8/) is some little bit of refactoring, to make the code simpler, please build on that.

Comment: Great Explanation, thanks a lot. I am just starting out, hence my code does not always make much sense. I am now going to attempt to link the random continent to its specific page such as if Africa is populated it will redirect me to The Africa HTML page and describe the continent. Any simple suggestions on that? @gdyrrahitis

Comment: You mean, when you choose randomly a continent, by pressing the magnifying glass icon, you should be redirected to the respective continent HTML page automatically? You can do this in the `drawcontinent ` method, by fetching the anchor element of the continent links. Check out here. https://jsfiddle.net/898xpu2z/1/

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and tried to run it. It seems to be getting the correct value but it still does not redirect that random choice to its respective page. It does populate the message "redirecting to the continent page" but stays on the original page. I updated the code and uploaded it above. cant figure out whats missing. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, because I have commented out the line that clicks on the anchor element. If you uncomment the `link.click();` line and comment out the alert you can get your expected behavior. Please read the comments on code, I've added them in order to help you.
Take this code and fiddle around, try to make it work your needs.

Comment: I have done as you mentioned but it still does not redirect to the relative page. I uploaded it to the server to show the exact process. [link](http://studentweb.cdm.depaul.edu/~anagatki/final/home.html)

Comment: I found a solution for the issue,  'setTimeout(function() {
      if (continentObject.continent === "North America"){
           window.location.href = "northamerica.html";
       }
   }, 2000 ); ' and now it redirects. Once again thank you for your help, much appreciated.